# Model property object not showing up

Tags: django

I try to calculate the average rating for my user. I triede to define property so it calculates and shows automatically.

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, default='undefinedusername')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True,null=True,blank=True)

    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        return self.usercomments.all().aggregate(Avg('rate')).get('rate__avg', 0.00)
        
class UserComment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='usercomments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='usercomments_author')
    rate = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rating_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    usercomments_set = UserCommentSerializer(source='usercomments', required=False, many=True)
   
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
                  
    def get_rating_count(self, language):
        return language.usercomments.count()

 
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs.get('id') == self.context['request'].user.pk:
            return attrs
        raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
```

Here is my result:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "8b0efd7e-06ac-4d57-a347-e9ffe79c3c31",
            "usercomments_set": [
                {
                    "id": "61c5b21e-3456-4a13-83c4-4557cd621af6",
                    "rate": 4,
                    "profile": "8b0efd7e-06ac-4d57-a347-e9ffe79c3c31",
                    "author": "f474d116-ec1d-498b-a166-7af3fa8cfd59"
                }
            ],
            "rating_count": 1,
            "username": "undefinedusername",
            "email": "testmail@gmail.com",
        },
}
```

Everything else except `average_rating` shows up.

What is the issue?Where did I make the mistake?